Making a mirror structure of a structure from Quantum ESPRESSO input file
I have two Quantum ESPRESSO input files. They are supposed to be mirror like. I want to check whether they are actually mirror or not. Is there any tool or way to convert one structure to it's mirror and then compare those input files (any steps or weblinks would also be helpful). Any simpler examples would also be appreciated.

If you share the input file I could write a parser for you

You could do it in python in a few lines of code. I'm sure you could use ase or phonopy or many other tools to parse the file for you and get atom positions if you don't want to do that yourself.

Thanks, both of you. It is now solved. Primarily I used an excel file here to make the mirror structure. For x-reflected, the positions are multiplied by '-1'. Similar for y and z reflected cases as well.
